# Kyro serialization error

Tags: java, serialization, kryo

I was working off of my thumbdrive with eclipse at school and brought the thumbdrive home.

I suddenly got this error the next time I ran the program:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create serializer "com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer" for class: com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.FrameworkMessage$RegisterTCP
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.newSerializer(Kryo.java:338)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.newDefaultSerializer(Kryo.java:317)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.getDefaultSerializer(Kryo.java:310)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.register(Kryo.java:354)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.KryoSerialization.<init>(KryoSerialization.java:33)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.KryoSerialization.<init>(KryoSerialization.java:25)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.Client.<init>(Client.java:73)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.Client.<init>(Client.java:55)
    at test.TestClient.<init>(TestClient.java:32)
    at test.TestClient.main(TestClient.java:39)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:532)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.newSerializer(Kryo.java:325)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface org.objectweb.asm.MethodVisitor, but class was expected
    at com.esotericsoftware.reflectasm.FieldAccess.insertConstructor(FieldAccess.java:144)
    at com.esotericsoftware.reflectasm.FieldAccess.get(FieldAccess.java:109)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.rebuildCachedFields(FieldSerializer.java:104)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.<init>(FieldSerializer.java:50)
    ... 14 more
```

I have never seen this kind of error and I'm not sure how to fix it. It happens every time I use the kryonet library. Any solutions available?

Answer (score 1):

A partner at work had the same error. It was caused by using an old "asm" library. He was using 3.X when the latest Kryo (2.18 as of this writing) requires asm 4.x. Updating the asm library fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

as Nushio answer, but it seems that you have libraries conflict, you have multiple dependencies that refer to different version of asm, you need figure out witch one's who causses the conflict by executing `mvn dependency:tree`. After that, you have to make maven exclusion in the dependency that refer to the wrong asm version (< 4.x).